# Google speech recognition API credentials error

Tags: python

I am trying to integrate a the google speech recognition API, but i keel getting an error saying ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError. I've been searching and I keep seeing something like : `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]`, but I don't know where actually to type that in the terminal and where to save the .json file. Is there a way I can correct this?

```
import argparse
import base64
import json

from googleapiclient import discovery
import httplib2
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


DISCOVERY_URL = ('https://{api}.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                 'version={apiVersion}')


def get_speech_service():
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default().create_scoped(
        ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials.authorize(http)

    return discovery.build(
        'speech', 'v1beta1', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URL)


def main(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file.

    Args:
        speech_file: the name of the audio file.
    """
    with open(speech_file, 'rb') as speech:
        speech_content = base64.b64encode(speech.read())

    service = get_speech_service()
    service_request = service.speech().syncrecognize(
        body={
            'config': {
                'encoding': 'LINEAR16',  # raw 16-bit signed LE samples
                'sampleRate': 16000,  # 16 khz
                'languageCode': 'en-US',  # a BCP-47 language tag
            },
            'audio': {
                'content': speech_content.decode('UTF-8')
                }
            })
    response = service_request.execute()
    print(json.dumps(response))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'speech_file', help='Full path of audio file to be recognized')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.speech_file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to export the credentials to the environment.

For mac -

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

For Windows via PowerShell-

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Where `[PATH]` is path to the `Json` file containing credentials. Here's a link for [setting up authentication for server to server production applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production)

Comment: Updated @ChiroOgbo